# SQL query returns zero rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find for each user, the join date and the number of orders they made as a buyer in 2019.

```
Table: Users
+----------------+---------+
| Column Name    | Type    |
+----------------+---------+
| user_id        | int     |
| join_date      | date    |
| favorite_brand | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

user_id is the primary key of this table.
This table has the info of the users of an online shopping website where users can sell and buy items.

Table: Orders

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| order_id      | int     |
| order_date    | date    |
| item_id       | int     |
| buyer_id      | int     |
| seller_id     | int     |
+---------------+---------+
```

order_id is the primary key of this table.
item_id is a foreign key to the Items table.
buyer_id and seller_id are foreign keys to the Users table.

Table: Items

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| item_id       | int     |
| item_brand    | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
item_id is the primary key of this table.
```

Input:

Users table:

```
+---------+------------+----------------+
| user_id | join_date  | favorite_brand |
+---------+------------+----------------+
| 1       | 2018-01-01 | Lenovo         |
| 2       | 2018-02-09 | Samsung        |
| 3       | 2018-01-19 | LG             |
| 4       | 2018-05-21 | HP             |
+---------+------------+----------------+
```

Orders table:

```
+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
| order_id | order_date | item_id | buyer_id | seller_id |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
| 1        | 2019-08-01 | 4       | 1        | 2         |
| 2        | 2018-08-02 | 2       | 1        | 3         |
| 3        | 2019-08-03 | 3       | 2        | 3         |
| 4        | 2018-08-04 | 1       | 4        | 2         |
| 5        | 2018-08-04 | 1       | 3        | 4         |
| 6        | 2019-08-05 | 2       | 2        | 4         |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

Items table:

```
+---------+------------+
| item_id | item_brand |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | Samsung    |
| 2       | Lenovo     |
| 3       | LG         |
| 4       | HP         |
+---------+------------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+
| buyer_id  | join_date  | orders_in_2019 |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 1         | 2018-01-01 | 1              |
| 2         | 2018-02-09 | 2              |
| 3         | 2018-01-19 | 0              |
| 4         | 2018-05-21 | 0              |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

I wrote the following solution but it doesn't work. Kindly explain what is wrong with it.

```
select u.user_id as buyer_id, u.join_date as join_date, count(o.order_id) as orders_in_2019
from Users u join Orders o on u.user_id = o.buyer_id
where o.order_date < date('2010-01-01') and o.order_date >= date('2019-01-01')
group by u.user_id;
```

This gives me empty result.

Comment: There is no date that exists before 2010-01-01 AND after 2019-01-01, regardless of result the table contents. Also you don't need `date()` around dates, they are dates already.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the date typo(o.order_date < '2010-01-01') you appear to want all users even if they have no orders in 2019 so left join and conditional aggregation seems appropriate

```
select u.user_id as buyer_id, u.join_date as join_date
       ,sum(case when o.order_date < '2020-01-01' and o.order_date >= '2019-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from users u 
left join Orders o on u.user_id = o.buyer_id
group by u.user_id ;

+----------+------------+------+
| buyer_id | join_date  | cnt  |
+----------+------------+------+
|        1 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |
|        2 | 2018-02-09 |    2 |
|        3 | 2018-01-19 |    0 |
|        4 | 2018-05-21 |    0 |
+----------+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not select a direct element that is not in the group by close

```
select g_user.buyer_id, Users.join_date as join_date , g_user.orders_in_2019 From (select u.user_id as buyer_id, count(o.order_id) as orders_in_2019 From Users u 
join Orders o on u.user_id = o.buyer_id
where o.order_date < date('2010-01-01') and o.order_date >= date('2019-01-01')
group by u.user_id) 
as g_user join Users on g_user.buyer_id = Users.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your date is not correct in sql:

```
o.order_date < date('2010-01-01')
```

It is obvious none of your order is before 2010. You should change to

```
o.order_date < date('2020-01-01')
```

Comment: sorry that is a typo. I did it right when I was running it.